# Parameterize table names with prepared statement query

Tags: php, mysql

In preparation for creating a forms wrapper in php, I need a use of dynamic names of tables when working with databases. This is because I have many different tables for insertion of data from various forms into a single wrapper. Writing specific queries for each table separately, it seems impractical method, on the other hand prepared statement not supported with parameterized table names. Starting from the fact that in programming there is no unsolvable problem, I tried hard to find solution through expert literature and web-forums, but unfortunately without success. I would very much appreciate if anyone knows an elegant solution for this!

```
<?php
……
    $dname = date("dmyHis", time());
    $tpath = $_POST['tpath'].$dname.".txt";
    $tdate = date("dmyHis");
    if (isset($_POST["table-name"])){
        $tname = $_POST["table-name "]; /** not sanitized yet */
        $prep = "INSERT INTO $tname  (t_name, t_path) VALUES (?, ?)"; /** it works if not var  */
        if ($qry = $conn->prepare($prep)){
            $qry->bind_param('ss', $tdate, $tpath);
            if (!$qry->execute()){
                header('Location: ../error.php?err=fail : INSERT tname');
                exit();
            }
            mysqli_close($conn);
        }else{
            header("Location: ../error.php?err=Database error: table-name is >> " .$tname ." cannot prepare statement INSERT tname");
            exit();
        }
    }else{
        echo "<script>alert('SHIT ISSET tname');</script>";
        exit();
    }
……
?>
```

Comment: Abstract the `table-name` parameter to some kind of ID value that maps to the real, known (& safe table) name, str_replace() that into the SQL string.

Comment: @Alex. Thanks for the answer. This is a rather interesting approach. I've tried several times as advised but without success. Meanwhile I noticed that $ _POST [ "table-name"] returns no result, although passes "if (isset ..", does not pass the "var_dump" and by "JQuery $ .Ajax" sends the right value along with ".serializeArray ()" and "myFrm.push ({name: ..". Of course I will answer, but I have to analyze this problem first and will try again, although I'm not quite clear how to do it.

Comment: @Alex. I'm sorry people, obviously I've realized something wrong! Namely I always encountered a responses or learnings that with "prepare query" for security reasons, can not use a variable for a name table. In my case it works great! The error was from "lapsus scriptum" nature, which was not intercepted by any error-handler (preparing array for $.post: myForm.push({name: 'tdName', ‘value’}); instead of: myForm.push({name: 'tdName',  value: ‘value’});), and now it’s work with parameterizing table name! Anyway sir, your advice I already used as extra protection! I am grateful to you.